# Is Zircon Boot Image (ZBI) essential for bootin the Zircon kernel?

Tags: c, kernel, bootloader, boot, fuchsia

The [kernel entrypoint](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/759de0da630ed07c68a1f3a64ab1c0c73f0cc550/zircon/kernel/top/main.cc#58) for the Zircon kernel calls [platform_early_init()](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/759de0da630ed07c68a1f3a64ab1c0c73f0cc550/zircon/kernel/platform/generic-arm/platform.cc#533) where it gets the zbi_paddr from the .S file and then passes to `pdev_init`

```
void* zbi_vaddr = paddr_to_physmap(zbi_paddr);
zbi_header_t* header = (zbi_header_t*)zbi_vaddr;
ramdisk_base = header;
zbi_root = reinterpret_cast<zbi_header_t*>(ramdisk_base);
pdev_init(zbi_root);
```

Where [pdev_init](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/759de0da630ed07c68a1f3a64ab1c0c73f0cc550/zircon/kernel/dev/pdev/pdev.cc#52) is responsible for starting drivers like uart.

It looks like the drivers through `pdev_run_hooks` (on the same file), where it walks through the zbi file and finds each driver information.

So it looks like ZBI is essential for booting?

I ask because I compiled the zircon kernel and got

> lz@vm:~/fuchsia/out/default/kernel_arm64$ ls gen
> image.build-id.stamp  kernel.zbi  toolchain.ninja
> zircon.elf.build-id.stamp  zircon.elf.map image  image.map
> obj         zircon.elf       zircon.elf-gdb.py

as you see it produces a `zircon.elf`, which theoretically could be ran, but I think ZBI information is essential for booting otherwise it would panic. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Zircon expects the bootloader to pass up a *Zircon Boot Image (ZBI)* object that it can parse.

This image contains a lot of information that is useful for system startup, for example, it contains physical memory ranges, the kernel cmdline, cpu topology information, peripherals information, and even a read-only filesystem used for bootstrapping userspace.

You can read more in the ["Zircon Kernel to userspace bootstrapping" documentation](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/concepts/booting/userboot?hl=en#boot_loader_and_kernel_startup). The ZBI Format is described in [`zircon/system/public/zircon/boot/image.h`](https://cs.opensource.google/fuchsia/fuchsia/+/main:zircon/system/public/zircon/boot/image.h;drc=6704353866a90c194101c57adb8d09ad2587e5f6).

In the `vim2` branch for the u-boot repo, [you can see how the bootloader assembles and appends](https://third-party-mirror.googlesource.com/u-boot/+/refs/heads/astro/board/amlogic/g12a_estelle_p2/zircon.c#116) the zbi items before booting into zircon.